# ComplexPattern in tblgen (llvm)

Tags: llvm

Can someone please specifically tell what a "complex pattern" really is? I mean at some place it includes `[frameindex]` as an operand, at other places it takes in `[add, frameindex]` as operands. The only thing I understand is that it is used to emit multiple output nodes. Is my understanding correct?